# using android native libs on PC

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have an apk with native .so libs, compiled for all architectures: armabi, mips, x86 and x86_64. I want to use these libs in my java app.

As i suppose, for building app on desktop i need to copy .so file from x86_64 folder anywhere on my PC, i've copied it to ~/IdeaProjects/ecg/lib/x86_64. After that i provided to VM path to this file as follows: `-Djava.library.path=/home/user/IdeaProjects/ecg/lib/x86_64`

Then i wrote wrapper for using this library on my project. In static initializer of wrapper i trying to load the library like that (my library file named libnative-lib.so):

```
   static
   {
       System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
   }
```

And during loading library i receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user/IdeaProjects/ecg/lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so: liblog.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

So what is liblog.so? Where can i get it? I tried to dig and all what i found was compiled liblog.so for different arches on github. I've found one for x86_64 [there](https://github.com/innogames/android-ndk/blob/master/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib/liblog.so), put it near my native lib file, but the exception didn't disappear.

What can i do for achieving my goal?

**UPD**
`sudo apt install android-liblog && android-liblog-dev` and provide LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/android resolve this issue. But now i'm received next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/user/IdeaProjects/ecg/lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so: invalid ELF header
```

**UPDUPD** finally i've copied all dependent libs from android sdk folder (Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-24/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64) and exceptions has gone. Now app simply falls with this report:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=11338, tid=0x00007ffaccb05700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user/IdeaProjects/ecg/hs_err_pid11338.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: "I want to use these libs in my java app" -- do you mean some sort of Java desktop or server program? Shouldn't you be recompiling that C/C++ code as part of building that desktop or server program?

Comment: yep. it's desktop java application. i cannot recompile it from sources because i haven't any sources. i have update my question.

Comment: "because i haven't any sources" -- then you need to talk to whoever you licensed those binaries from, to provide you with ones that will work with your chosen desktop/server OS.

Comment: What will be the difference? Unless .so file from x86_64 wasn't compiled for x86_64 processors?. Why i cannot use already compiled lib?

Comment: Technically, because dependent libraries may not exist for the platform on which you are running. Beyond that, you need to purchase a license for those binaries, as licensing terms will vary by platform, distribution model, etc.

Comment: u say as manager or seller, and i ask as software developer and reverse engineer

Comment: Was your able to solve this problem?.. I need same thing, with same lib, for same purpose..

Comment: @Kosmos unfortunately not

Comment: @borune Hi. Any news on how to fix this problem?

Comment: @SergeyK. unfortunately not at all